# Generate a csv dataset file which is explained from a folder structure in python

Tags: python, csv, machine-learning, dataset, data-science

I have a folder "Dataset" which contains a bunch of folders with their own names. Each folder contains n number of frames, which are sequential images. n ranges from 5-20 images. I need a python code, which iterates through all the folders in the "Dataset" and from each folder, divides them into chunks of 7. It writes each chunk's path into a single row. Than it takes the remaining files from the same folder and stores in a new row of the csv file. It than goes into another folder inside the dataset class and does the same thing for all folders in the dataset.

Comment: You may have a look at `os.walk()`, that will recursively go through your directory and list each files in each folder. E.g.: `for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/my/path")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is a way that I can do it.

```
import os
import csv

dataset_path = "Datasets/VOS/train/masks"

with open("data.csv", "w", newline="") as csvfile:

    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)

    for folder in os.listdir(dataset_path):

        folder_path = os.path.join(dataset_path, folder)

        files = os.listdir(folder_path)

        for i in range(0, len(files), 7):
            chunk = files[i:i+7]
            names = [os.path.join(dataset_path, folder, file) for file in chunk]
            writer.writerow(names)
```